# reflectance value ranges from -3.40282e38 to 3.40282e38 in qgis

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, gis

reflectance value ranges from -3.40282e38 to 3.40282e38 in qgis atmoshpherically corrected image, I want my value to range between 0-1 how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to map into the range $[0,1]$ is by using the sigmoid [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), however, such a large range will lead to very similar values.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it's useless.  Those large absolute values indicate either preprocessing errors or are codes for missing values.  In either case, rescaling won't fix the problem.